# File.ListFiles returns out of date file list on Android

Tags: android, file, android-activity

I have an Android activity that gets a list of files from a directory using the File.listFiles() function.  This returns an array of Files exactly as I'd expect.  This activity has the option to start another activity which allows users to create a new file in the same directory.

When I return from the second activity, having created a new file, I call the File.listFiles() function again to get the updated list, but the returned array doesn't include the newly generated file.

When I restart the app the filelist is correct with the newly created file included.  It is as if the Activity is caching the result or not re-checking the directory.

Anyone else had this problem and/or know how to fix it?

Many thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix this now. The problem was caused by the fact I was writing the files in the second activity's onStop() function which appeared to be called after the first activity's onResume().  I've chnaged the code to save onBackButtonPress() and everything now works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The system scans the SD card when it is mounted to find any new image (and other) files. If you are programmatically adding a file, then you can use this class:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html

Comment: Is a rescan of the sdcard necessary though?  I thought the mediascanner was used for **Android** to know about any new files.   File.listFiles is a standard java function and I wouldn't have thought it would have any dependence on Android code?

Comment: If you want to activate android system to start scan, you need to broadcast message indicating sd card is mounted. Then android system would automatically do this.